# How to handle the expiration of login cookies if a user is inactive for more than a set time using Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, ruby-on-rails-3, cookies, authentication

I am trying to manage the login session of users that navigate in my RoR3 application.

I set a cookie when they sign in and I would like that their authentication expires after a few minutes of inactivity, for example 15 minutes.

**How to achieve that?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This doesn't directly answer your question, but I strongly suggest using something like Devise for authentication instead of rolling your own.

Devise provides a `timeoutable` configuration flag, as well as a timeout value covering how long user sessions can be inactive before being logged out.

Answer (score 3):

You could setup a property in your session. Something like

```
session[:expire_time] = 15.minutes.since
```

Then, in your applicationController you can check if your user has been away enough time to be logged out, if not then you renew his expiration time, something like:

```
 class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
   before_filter :check_expire

   def check_expire
     if session[:expire_time] and session[:expire_time] < Time.now
       #your code to logout the user
     else
       session[:expire_time] = 15.minutes.since
     end
     return true
  end
end
```

Comment: I think that a malicious person can hack that session so that it will have no expiration time.

Answer (score 1):

You can also set the expiration time of the cookie that sets their session. In your configuration :

```
env["rack.session.options"][:expire_after] = 15.minutes
```

This works perfectly for the use case you described, because it will be reset every time the server responds, but it gives you a little less control.

Here's a good article about it :

http://augustl.com/blog/2010/dynamic_session_expiration_time_in_rails_3